# why jQuery defaultDate not update current date?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Here is the code using to update defaultDate to a text field at document ready, but its not updating the current date.

```
  var currentDate = new Date();
        $("#tbdate").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            defaultDate: currentDate
        });
```

Kindly let me know what wrong I did?

Comment: `defaultDate` selects the date *in* the datepicker. Are you saying you want to set the text field's value to today's date?

Comment: yes, I need to set the current date at page load on text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deafaultDate` does not update the control associated with the date picker, but `setDate` does so try this:

```
$("#tbdate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put `currentDate` in to your input field by default (on page load) you can try this:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
$("#tbdate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    defaultDate: currentDate
}).datepicker("setDate", "0");
//^^
```

(Added the last line so it sets the `defaultDate` in your input field.)